# Writing an equals method to compare two arrays

Tags: java, methods, equals

I have the following code, I believe something is off in my equals method but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
public class Test {
    private double[] info;
    public Test(double[] a){
        double[] constructor = new double[a.length];        
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
                constructor[i] = a[i];
        }       
        info = constructor;
    }

    public double[] getInfo(){      
        double[] newInfo = new double[info.length];     
        for(int i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
            newInfo[i] = info[i];
        }   
        return newInfo;
    }
    public double[] setInfo(double[] a){
        double[] setInfo = new double[a.length];    
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            setInfo[i] = a[i];
        }
        return info;
    }
    public boolean equals(Test x){
        return (this.info == x.info);
    }
}
```

and in my tester class I have the following code:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] info = {5.0, 16.3, 3.5 ,79.8} 
        Test test1 = new Test();
        test 1 = new Test(info);
        Test test2 = new Test(test1.getInfo());
        System.out.print("Tests 1 and 2 are equal: " + test1.equals(test2));
    }
}
```

the rest of my methods seem to function correctly, but when I use my equals method and print the boolean, the console prints out false when it should print true.

Comment: why not use `Arrays.equals(double[] a, double[] a2)`?

Comment: As was already pointed out by @Jason, you compare object references with `==`. Aside from that, your code is improperly formated and you use highly confusing variable names (`constructor` in the constructor). Furthermore you may want to take a look at the [`Arrays` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) since it provides some functionality you can use to make your life easier.

Comment: The method `setInfo` fills an array copy `setInfo` but does not assign it to the field `info` and also should better `return getInfo();` to return just a copy too.

Answer (score 1):

You are just comparing memory references to the arrays. You should compare the contents of the arrays instead.

Do this by first comparing the length of each array, then if they match, the entire contents of the array one item at a time.

Here's one way of doing it (written without using helper/utility functions, so you understand what's going on):

```
public boolean equals(Test x) {

    // check if the parameter is null
    if (x == null) {
        return false;
    }

    // check if the lengths are the same
    if (this.info.length != x.info.length) {
        return false;
    }

    // check the elements in the arrays
    for (int index = 0; index < this.info.length; index++) {
        if (this.info[index] != x.info[index]) {
            return false;
        } Aominè
    }

    // if we get here, then the arrays are the same size and contain the same elements
    return true;
}
```

As @Aominè commented above, you could use a helper/utility function such as (but still need the null check):

```
public boolean equals(Test x) {

    if (x == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return Arrays.equals(this.info, x.info);
}
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. How would I go about this? I'm guessing you would first write if (Test.length != x.length){return false;}  but what would you write for the else statement?

Comment: @RobertJohnson - you should override the equals method provided by Object. This takes an Object as a parameter, so that means that you need to check the type of the parameter using `instanceof` to make sure it is a `Test` object.

Comment: I fixed the equals method, but does something look wrong with my setInfo method? when I use double[] info1 = {1.5,2,2.5,3} and then call it via test1.setInfo(info1), when I print (test1.toString) it prints [0.0] instead of [1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]

Comment: In `setInfo` change `double[] setInfo = new double[a.length];` to `info = new double[a.length];` and then change `setInfo[i] = a[i];` to `info[i] = a[i];`.